# Caching types in Cassandra 2.0

Tags: cassandra

I have a small confusion with caching types in Cassandra 2.0. Is 'all' meaning entire table data caching or recently accessed (keys + rows) caching ? For example, if the table has 'n' rows, will it cache only recently accessed 'x' rows (or) cache all 'n' rows irrespective of accessibility ? Can you please explain more details about all/keys_only/rows_only types ?

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/reference/referenceTableAttributes.html

> caching
>       (Default: keys_only) Optimizes the use of cache memory without manual tuning. Set caching to one of the following values:
>
> ```
>     all
>     keys_only
>     rows_only
>     none
>
> Cassandra weights the cached data by size and access frequency. Use this parameter to specify a key or row cache instead of a table
> ```
>
> cache, as in earlier versions.

Thanks,

Ramesh

Comment: You may find this useful : http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/maximizing-cache-benefit-with-cassandra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ALL` means a union of `ROWS_ONLY` and `KEYS_ONLY` caching.  It does not imply that the whole table is going to be cached.

Source:  from the source code (I looked at trunk == 2.1 currently); search for uses of `Caching.ALL`, `Caching.KEYS_ONLY` and `Caching.ROWS_ONLY`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel ! I am planning to use a table for alternative to MemCache. So based on your reply, I assume that it is correct to set Caching "ALL" for that table. Please share your views on this.

Comment: Yes, I think that could work if you have lots of memory, but beware that depending on your queries, you can't always skip going to the main store, because you don't know if your cached results satisfy the query.  It will work if you ask for one row at a time, for sure.  There are some major changes to caching, but they're not yet available in a production branch. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5357 .

Comment: As Daniel had stated , your idea of using all will backfire if you are creating more rows than columns. It will also backfire if you are creating wide rows too(Since you are eating up your memory eventually in the name of caching)